# Div full height of TD, with text vertically middle

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I know this question was put several times here, but didn't find a proper answer. I managed a workaround to make div full height of td. But seems impossible to align the text in the middle vertically. Any idea how can I accomplish this? I would like it to be responsive. I mean to work on all devices. Thanks.

```
<tr>
    <td>
        Small text
    </td>
    <td class="" style="height: 1px; height: 100%">
        <div style="position: relative">
            <span class="centered-text"> A very long text that I want to be centered inside parent div and of course parent td.</span>
        </div> 
    </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing any of your code, it's a little difficult to give you an exact answer. But my favorite method for solving this problem, especially for responsive solutions, (as long as you don't need to support anything below IE9) is the following:

```
.text-container {
  position: relative;
}

.centered-text {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

If it also needs to be centered horizontally, use the following addition and replace the transform properties:

```
.centered-text {
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Edit: updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2665abzy/3/) with position relative, to fill space - shows final fully centered result.

Comment: Thanks. I usually avoid position absolute, but this time I am happy with this solution. Cheers.

Comment: No problem! I generally agree. My usual rule of thumb is that as long as there is a relative parent in the flow, you're generally safe to use absolute positioning.

Comment: I just faced another problem. If the text centerd is very long it overlaps the parent container. The parent td is not increased. I updated the question with html.

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense since that text element doesn't fill any space. Will the text be dynamic? Did you add html to this post or create a new one? I've updated my fiddle above so the text-container is actually relative (this works for top positioning but not left and right).

Comment: Yes. It will be dynamic. Probably in my case is not a big problem. My text isnot very long, but I'm kinda perfectionist and want to cover all cases.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding the following CSS to your div:

```
div{
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

The display attribute will cause the div to behave more like a table cell, meaning the vertical align style will have an effect.

Example: http://codepen.io/JasonGraham/pen/aZbdmy

Comment: Thanks for hint. I tried this but display:table-cell doesn't let my div same height of parent TD.

Comment: Apologies, my misunderstanding! If you're looking to maintain the div height, I'd opt for a similar solution to that provided by @ghost_dad above. Display the text relative within the parent container using "top" to align vertically :).

Comment: div { height: 100%; } lets your div fill the whole truth element. Easier would be <td style="vertical-align: middle; height: 100%;">your text here</td>

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking about that. But I need a border that will be applied with some margin. So this does not make me happy. Or is it possible to apply border some pixels inside td? I don't think so.

Answer (score 1):

Use inline CSS

```
style="display:table-cell;vertical-align: middle;"
```

You can set height of `td` in table also like

```
style="display:table-cell;vertical-align: middle;  height:200px;"
```

Example:

```
<tr>

<td  style="display:table-cell;vertical-align: middle;">
    <h1>some text</h1>
</td>

<td>
    <img src="imagepath.jpg" height="100" width="100"
</td>

</tr>
```